# Looking for a working code example in python for creating a post

Tags: rest-api, api

There are numerous wrong, old, conflicting, and non-working examples for posting in WordPress using python. Every example I have seen has failed and error messages leave a lot of possible solutions. Does basic auth work? Does using application credentials work?

Is there a minimum working example out there?

```
url = 'https://demo.com'
#application creds
username = 'fedup-with-examples'
password = 'yNqm 50lb zqoD 1PHk Qbrg ulWX'


# The post data
data = {
    'title': 'My New Post',
    'content': 'This is the content of my new post.',
    'status': 'draft'  # Use 'draft' to save the post as a draft
}
# Send the HTTP request


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

payload = json.dumps({
        "status":"draft",
        "title": "title_translation_text",
        "content": "content_translation_text"
    })


r = requests.post(url= url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', data=data, headers=headers, auth=(username, password))


print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

In terms of error, I get the following:

```
401
{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Now the credentials relate to the application passwords.From `Users->Profile->Application Passwords`

Comment: [The REST API supports application passwords since WP 5.6.](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#basic-authentication-with-application-passwords) Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/421721/edit) to include the error(s) you're seeing; that might help us help you.

Comment: @PatJ Added these.